# Remove trailing slash and then execute successive RewriteCond statements

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My website have some of the links ending with slash (/). Following are some of the example links of my site.

1. www.website/foo/
2. www.website/bar

Following is the .htaccess file,

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond "%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/static/%{REQUEST_URI}.html"  -f
    RewriteRule "^(.+)" "%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/static/$1.html"  [L]

    </IfModule>
```

In the .htaccess file, I am checking if there is an html file with the same name of REQUEST_URI in static directory.

www.website/bar is working fine.

www.website/foo/ is not working. That is obvious, because there is a trailing slash.

Please help me to remove the trailing slash and check if the html version of REQUEST_URI is present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to match the slash outside the capture group. `^(.+)/` will match `/foo/` or any uri string ending with a slash. To match both non-trailing slash and Trailing slash uris just put a `?` at the end  `^(.+)/?` .

Update your Rule with the following:

```
 RewriteRule "^(.+)/?" "%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/static/$1.html"  [L]
```